# Checkboxes like radio-buttons in Angular and Ionic

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of Ionic checkboxes, if I click one I want the others to be deselected. Here is an example of the list :

```
 <ion-checkbox  ng-model="creditCard" ng-change="p_method()">
            Credit Card
 </ion-checkbox>
 <ion-checkbox  ng-model="cash" ng-change="p_method()">
            Cash
 </ion-checkbox>
 <ion-checkbox  ng-model="check" ng-change="p_method()">
            Check
 </ion-checkbox>
```

In my controller I started writing something like this:

```
  function p_method(){
     $scope.creditCard = $scope.creditCard === true ? false : true;
     $scope.cash = $scope.cash === true ? false : true;
     $scope.check = $scope.check === true ? false : true;  
     ...........
    }
```

EDIT:

I could use radio-buttons but they can’t be all deselected.

Comment: if the user can only select one, shouldn't this be a *radio*-element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to work with the ng-true-value and ng-false-value of the checkbox. That way you can directly bind the selected payment method to your model.

**View**

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="(key,value) in vm.paymentTypes" ng-model="vm.paymentType" ng-true-value="'{{key}}'" ng-false-value="">{{value}}</ion-checkbox>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.paymentType = 'none';
  vm.paymentTypes = {
    'creditCard': 'Credit Card',
    'cash': 'Cash',
    'bankCheque': 'Bank cheque'
  };
});
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/p6Z5FMxE9vz2NbAlhqrl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my own issue:

In the view :

```
<ion-checkbox  ng-repeat="(key,value) in paymentsMethod" ng-model="value" ng-change="p_change(key)">{{key}}
</ion-checkbox>
```

Here is the controller with some service data (docDetails) fetched from the db:

```
    var paymentsMethod = {'credit card':false,'cash':false,'check':false};

    angular.forEach(paymentsMethod,function(value,key){
        if(key === docDetails.p_method){
            paymentsMethod[key] = true
        }
    });

    $scope.paymentsMethod = paymentsMethod;

    $scope.p_change = function(method){
        paymentsMethod = {'credit card':false,'cash':false,'check':false};
        angular.forEach(paymentsMethod, function(value,key){
            if(key === method){
                if(docDetails.p_method===method){
                    paymentsMethod[key]=true;
                }
                paymentsMethod[key] =  paymentsMethod[key] === true ? false : true;
            }
        });
        $scope.paymentsMethod = paymentsMethod;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to pass somethign in p_method in order to detect which checkbox was checked.
for example.

```
ng-change="p_method('creditCard')"
```

Comment: it is string not model, think twice before rating -ve

Comment: ng-model="creditCard" ng-change="p_method()" where according to you ,you are passing it inside function as parameter which doesnot make any sense at all because $scope.creditCard is accessible everywhere inside controller

Comment: it is 'creditCard' not creditCard. check the quotes.